# App installation failed

Tags: xcode, ios8, xcode6

In **Xcode 6 Beta 5**, when I attempt to run my app after building, I receive an error dialog that says:

> App installation failed
>
> Could not inspect the application package.

This happens on **iOS 8 Beta 5**, but not on **iOS 7.1.1**! I have not tested anything else.

Any ideas for how I can fix this?

Comment: If you already installed in device than try to deleting the app on device and install it again.

Comment: I've already tried that. Didn't help

Comment: It's happening to us on Xcode 6 GM when we run our app on iOS 8 GM devices. The weirdest thing is that it happens every second time: work, doesn't, work, doesn't, etc. Wether the code changes or not makes no difference.

Comment: I have exactly the same behavion here... still didnts figured out

Comment: Try restarting your computer. That sometimes works.

Answer (score 12):

I had this problem. `Solution is to uninstall the app. Then clean project and then install app.`

Comment: Just clean and then build/install works for me with Xcode 9.2

Answer (score 7):

I solved it by uninstalling(removing) the application from device manually and Run xcode application again. It will work.

Answer (score 7):

Try editing the scheme of app. Set Run and Archive to debug not release. I was able to solve by this process.

Answer (score 3):

I have had this happen to me about 3 times since moving to Beta 5 and Xcode beta 5. I usually navigate to my Organizer and select Projects. Find your project on the left and delete it. Next I close Xcode and restart both my Mac and my Testing Device! Has helped every time!

Comment: > Find your project on the left and delete it.

Answer (score 3):

Deleting the derived data folder worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

My solution which worked for me was to remove a symbolic link file referenced from a an directory entry an in my Build Phases->Copy Bundle Resources section. I had inadvertently placed the symbolic link there.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when using Xcode 9 beta, the problem was that I was trying to run an app on an iPhone 7 **targeting armv7 instead of arm64**.

This issue was not easy to track because I was building the app from Unity, so check the architecture configuration whenever you get this message.

Answer (score 0):

Problem: Few times, if you add app extension where you have file and info plist, extension's file and plist are assigned to target, is wrong causes issue rises.
Solution: Extension's all file should be assigned in App Extensions target, and info plist should not be assigned to any target.

Answer (score 0):

Restarted my iphone it worked for me.