# iOS app testing. App installation failed. No code signature found

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, debugging

I've tried to install my app on several iOS devices. But this thing didn't let me to.

[image]

I want to know, what the problem is and how should I solve it.

Comment: Have you clean your build or uninstall app from device and install again ?

Comment: surely you need to have a look on app distribution

Comment: @AshishThakkar yes, I've tried to

Comment: have you restart your xcode as well ?

Comment: @AshishThakkar yep, didn't work

Comment: i think you have to changed "other C flags" in Build Settings

Comment: @AshishThakkar it is completely clear. But I've changed my apple ID password. Can this be the case?

Comment: as per my knowledge it might not be an issue. but for safe side i think you have to create new certificate and make sure that your all device udid is added to your account.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

In my case, the problem was unsigned frameworks.

**Xcode 11 or above:**

Go to Build Phases, expand Embedded Frameworks and select all Code Sign on Copy checkboxes.

**Xcode 10 or earlier:**

Build Phases > Copy Files > Code Sign on Copy (select all checkboxes)

[image: Code Sign on Copy selected in every row]

Comment: doesn't work for xcode 10

Comment: Embed Frameworks> Check the "Code Sign on Copy" button for all frameworks for XCode 10.1

Comment: @NupurSharma In Xcode 10.2.1 Embed Frameworks> Check the "Code Sign on Copy" button not working. Do you know any other solution

Comment: I had removed the library which caused this problem. I could not find a single solution working for me.

Comment: I am using cocoa pods so there is no "Code Sing on Copy" in build phase

Comment: I am using xCode12. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 29):

I had this problem, this is what I did to resolve it:

- Run "clean" in Xcode
- Close Xcode
- Remove all data in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`
- Remove all xcuserdata folders in your project (check in your xcodeproj and project.xcworkspace directories)

**Only if you have Cocoapods** in your project:

- Run `pod deintegrate`.
- Remove your `.xcworkspace` if it was created by CocoaPods.
- Run `pod install` or `pod update`

Now you can open your fresh Xcode.

Hope this help you.

In my case the problem was created by adding a new cocoa touch framework.

Comment: Thanks! Removing  `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` was enough in my case.

Comment: pod deintegrate worked for me

Answer (score 21):

If "code sign on copy" fails, then check if you are modifying the frameworks in a run script after the "Embed Frameworks" phase.

If you are, then move the Run script to a position before the "Embed Frameworks" phase.

Comment: Can you explain how to do that?

Comment: From Target -> Build Phases you are able to drag and reorder the different tasks

Comment: Thank you, this was the issue for me.

Comment: Dueeeedeeeee, I cant thank you more. I have been looking for the solution for past 4 days. This now makes total sense. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 12):

In my case, I have created **an unsigned IPA file** and for this i had made some changes in SDKSetting.plist file (changed CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED = NO) and it should be always YES if you are running application on the device.

To resolve this follow the below steps:
**Steps to create unsigned IPA** (Tested on Xcode 9.4.1)

**Step 1:** Open finder > **Go to Folder..** as below screen

[image]

and then copy and past the below line:

**/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS*.*.sdk/SDKSettings.plist**

Open iPhoneOS.sdk as showing in below image:
[image]

**Step 2:**
Copy the SDKSettings plist in another folder because you can't make changes here:

**Step 3:** Make the change in duplicate

set **CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED to YES**
[image]

**Step 4:** Now replace duplicate Plist with the original one (Both names must be the same).
This will also ask admin permission to change.

********************************OR**************************************

If you will update your Xcode then the problem will also disappear because updated xcode will come with default SDKSetting.plist

Comment: My first question is why it would even turn into NO. This has to be YES all the time. I know why in my system it was NO because I installed iOSOpenDev Installer. 
This doesnt fix the issue.

Comment: @Alix in my case, I had created an unsigned IPA file that's why tuned to NO.

Comment: I see but then later part of the post is wrong where you said "If you will update your Xcode then the problem will also disappear because updated xcode will come with default SDKSetting.plist". Code Signing Required is by default is YES

Comment: @Alix second point is also correct, I had updated my code to newer available version and it became automatically YES from NO. Because you you will update your xcode the plist comes with default setting and by default it’s always YES.

Comment: Same problem here, I forgot I did modified SDKSetting.plist to create an unsigned IPA.
Reverting  AD_HOC_CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED to NO and restarting XCode got rid of the error message

Answer (score 2):

I also faced same issue. 
I tried all above solution none work from me.

Below stuff worked for me,

1. Select Build settings
2. Locate "Code Signing identity"
3. select "IOS Developer" or any other correct option for all.

Then build and run.

Comment: You save me. Many many thanks. After lots of solution, I got your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Folks, My problem's Root cause was modifications that were done by iOSOpenDev installer. I did restore the original plist file that was backed up by the installer. that solved my problem 
you need to look into the SDK directory to see if something funky has happened. 
at least one more option to try.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS<SDK version>.sdk/
```

example:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.4.sdk/
```

by default code signing must be turned on, if that is turned off then something funky happened. (for ref See Alok's answer below)

If nothing works. My recommendation would be to delete and reinstall Xcode as this error would not arise in the normal scenarios. So resetting Xcode can greatly reduce troubleshooting time.

Answer (score 0):

1) Try to clean project
2) Try to relaunch XCode
3) Reset your mac

Comment: I had this situation and I had to restart my iPhone and then it works. Do you have developer accounts or not? If not check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak

Comment: nope, didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Restarting my device fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

I have some issues during App upload to the Appstore then i Add Some Code
in Build Phase -> Run Script

done
I clean Build folder and remove t above code from Run Script 
And Build again and run on my Iphone it work fine

You can remove the code of run script or
check the check box of ."Run script only when installing " then also it will work

Answer (score 0):

Enabling "Automatically manage signing" solved the issue for me. (In the target settings, "General" tab, section "Signing")

Answer (score -4):

It is clear you do not have the developer and the distribution profile set for the devices you are trying to install the app.

Comment: I have developer key and have same error, actually it comes after success build, in script executing part.

Comment: There are many things that could cause this, not just the dev/dist profile for the devices. Such as code signing for third party frameworks.