# Xcode: App installation failed No code signature found

Tags: xcode, code-signing, xcode9

I want run app on real device ( iphone 6 or 8 )

But i get this error :

> App installation failed No code signature found.

I try all below solutions but not work for me:

[iOS app testing. App installation failed. No code signature found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371044/ios-app-testing-app-installation-failed-no-code-signature-found)

My xcode version is 9.2

I'm tired :(

Comment: have you created a valid development profile?

Comment: @Calvin yes, i can run on iphone 4 but cant run on 6 or 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I go to `project > build setting` and set `signing > code signing identity` to `iOS developer`

It work fine