# react-native zoom-bridge sdk build in ios real device not working but in emulator,it is working

Tags: react-native, zoom-sdk

it is showing unable to install.build is happening fine

No code signature found.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain

can anyone come up with a solution..thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Lious! Your problem is not RN-specific, it's about code signing on iOS. Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371044/ios-app-testing-app-installation-failed-no-code-signature-found

Answer (score 1):

Beside checking code-signing, also remember, that there are 2 Zoom iOS SDKS:
one for simulators and one for real devices.