# Unable to install app on debug mode device and also in ad hoc . But working in simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, app-store

I am unable to install my app on a real device while DEBUG running or in ad-hoc builds. However, I am able to run on a simulator. I did refer to many similar issues but couldn't find a solution. I assume it has something to do with the code signing of embedded frameworks, but as I said no proper guide could be found.[image] .
These are my frameworks added to my project

[image]

This is my install error. If distributed via ad-hoc it says "this app could not be installed because of the integrity".

Comment: are you sure your developer account is set up properly? "no code signature found" looks like your developer certificates are not up to date

Comment: yes. They are up to date. I double-checked it

Comment: did you see this question / answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371044/ios-app-testing-app-installation-failed-no-code-signature-found

And did you try to "Embed&Sign" all of them?

Comment: Yes .I did. but I it didn't help me either. However I fixed it later . I will update the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue arised for me when

- I removed an existing embedded library in my app .

How I solved it

- When I double checked the project , There was 2 more libraries which was dependent on the removed library for code signing(I assume it was this. Please correct me if I am wrong). So I removed these libraries too. The reason why I didn't removed it earlier was because I was not aware of it, as the project was passed to me only a few days ago.
- After that I ran the project and it worked fine
- The confusion arised because the app ran perfectly in simulator .But when try to run on a real device or distribute through an ad-hoc build, the error occurred (Refer my question screenshots)

Note - Please feel free to post a better explanation