# can't able to write to device (IOS Distribution) (XCODE 9.2)

Tags: ios, mobile

I have created distribution certificate and distribution Profile for IOS. 
Build success, I can able to install build in simulator. Same while installing in device showing success, signing successful and ends with

> 'APP INSTALLATION FAILED> CANT WRITE TO DEVICE'. for both developer and distribution profiles

I have checked same questions in stack overflow [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31002642/app-installation-failed-could-not-write-to-the-device)
Followed suggestions. still facing same issue.

Please let me know how to resolve this.

Comment: You need to use **developer certificate and Developer Profile** to install app on device using XCode, instead of distribution certificate and distribution Profile.

Comment: So. We can't install Distribution Profile based app directly from XCODE. How to run this distribution based app on my device.

Comment: Yes, You can't use Distribution Profile to install app directly from XCode. If you want to test with Distribution certificate, create an "AD-HOC Profile", With that you can install app using XCode, but it will not allow you to debug.

Comment: To debug app, You have to use **developer certificate and Developer Profile**.

Comment: I have small doubt. While creating Distribution profile. I have picked AD-HOC. Is this the same one which you are pointing. Is there any other form of AD-HOC

Comment: Yes, It is same.

Comment: then why its not running from Xcode . I have picked AD-HOC

Comment: You are Correct. I Have picked App-Store(NOT AD-HOC) while creating Distribution Profile. I'm using because of that.

Comment: @Surjeet. For Development profile too Its showing same error. Cant write to device.

Comment: Try after restarting your device.

Comment: restarted twice.No Changes, Same error